# WinRT FlipView Scrolling Event

Tags: windows-runtime

Is it possible to know, when a FlipView is sliding back or forth, what item is currently on screen? The only relevant event I can see is SelectionChanged, which only gets raised when the FlipView comes to a rest and not if the person is quickly flipping through multiple items. I want to implement a "page number" indicator that changes even when the FlipView has not come to a rest. I'm using C++/CX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the ScrollViewer that is part of the control template of the FlipView. To get hold of the control - you would use the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.getchildrencount.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) to scan the visual tree looking for it. Then perhaps the ScrollViewer's [ViewChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanged) event would let you see if the FlipView was manipulated.

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. The ScrollViewer's HorizontalOffset property gives me a "live" indication of the item that's on screen.

Comment: Ingenious idea, saved my day

Comment: There's nothing ingenious about it. People have been doing it for years although some warn against using `VisualTreeHelper` for perf reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is show a page number, you could DataBind the TextView displaying the number to the FlipView's SelectedIndex property. You'll need to create a ValueConverter that adds 1 to the SelectedIndex, but that'll only take a minute.

Comment: The problem is that the SelectedIndex won't be updated until the FlipView has reached a full stop